# Django: Unable to access attribute of foreign key

Tags: django

I have a Comment model with User as a foreign key, and simply want to render the username of the comment. The comment shows up on the page but the username doesn't, I've tried `comment.user` and `comment.user.username` and neither works and I'm not sure why.. Sorry if this is a really basic question.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

def comment(request, listing_id):
    listin = Listing.objects.get(id=listing_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        comment = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment.is_valid():
            comment = comment.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.listing = listin
            comment.save()
    return redirect("listing", listing_id=listing_id)
```

HTML code:

```
    {% for comment in comments %}
        <p>{{ comment.user.username }}: {{ comment.comment }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

Edit:
I have sinced removed the `blank=True` and `null=True` arguments for user in the Comment model so it looks like this, migrated the changes and added a few comments, the username still doesn't render even though the username shows up as a field value in the admin view for the Comment object.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

My User class simply inherits from the AbstractUser model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    watchlist = models.ManyToManyField(Listing)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: Likely because `.user` is `NULL`/`None`. Why did you make it `null=True`?

Comment: because I added the user field halfway and didn't want to affect the old entries.. but the username still shows up as a field in the admin view.

I just updated the model to remove the `blank=True` and `null=True` arguments too, migrated and the username still doesn't render..

Comment: Willem is right - if the user is blank for that specific comment you simply won't see anything in the template. Can you check if there is a user associated with that comment? Also, can your share your User model?

Comment: I have removed the blank and null arguments and migrated the changes, added some new comments but the username still doesn't show.. the User model inherits from AbstractUser, I have edited my post above to show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `User` is the admin user, if you are not already logged as admin then the comment will be saved without a user as `request.user` is `None`.

You can force the user to be logged in by adding the `login_required` decorator before the view function

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
...
@login_required
def view(request)
    ...
```

This way you can only comment if you are already logged in and if not, then you will be redirected to the login page and once you are logged in the comment will be saved.

Comment: I added the comment while logged in and the admin view does show my username as the field value of the comment object..

but I added the @login_required decorator and posted a new comment but the username still doesn't show..

Answer (score 0):

I see there you have no user data, you have to do this to prevent user comments from being available

```
from django.contrib.messages import error
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def comment(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        error("....")
        return redirect(reverse("foo"))
    ...
```